# "screenshot" vs "screen capture"

Tags: synonyms

"screenshot" vs "screen capture"

context : the picture of the screen of a cellphone / desktop

1) Which is the most commonly used ?

2) Is one of the two confusing for some not native speaker ?

Note: Google return way more result for "screenshot", but some official documentation use "screen capture".

EDIT:
Thanks guys. You helped me a lot.
I choose to use "screenshot". reasons:

- to avoid confusion with the picture and the action of taking the picture.
- screen capture could refer to video. I do not want this double meaning.
- it seem more used (google result count)

Comment: Don't forget that there is a dedicated keyboard button named **[`Prt Scn`](http://www.theedublogger.com/files/2009/11/Prtscn.jpg)** which literally translates to `Print Screen` even though it does not send anything to the printer. It just takes a screenshot/screen capture/screen grab of your current desktop and loads it into memory, you can then use `Ctrl+V` to paste it into a Word document; this includes all monitors. I always use screenshot.

Comment: You can also say the shortened of screen capture, which is "screencap." My office tends to favor that word over the others, but I can't tell you about more general usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the two expressions  have  different meanings, *screen capture* refers to the action, *screenshot* is the result of the action:

> - ***Screen capture or grabber software allows you to take a snapshot of the computer's screen or part of the screen.*** You can then paste the picture into a document or save it as a file. If you create presentations or handouts, you may want to copy pictures from the computer screen to put them into your project.

***[Screenshot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/screenshot):***

> - An image of the data displayed on the screen of a computer or mobile device:
>     *a screenshot of the band’s Facebook page* (ODO)

***[Screen capture](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/screen_capture.html):***

> - ***Refers to the act of copying what is currently displayed on a screen to a file or printer***. If the system is in graphics mode, the screen capture will result in a graphics file containing a bit map of the image. If the system is in text mode, the screen capture will normally load a file with ASCII codes.

(Webopedia.com)

Comment: I think that this is connotation rather than denotation, but if you see something advertised as "screen capture" software, chances are it records video. A 'screenshot' is just a still image of your screen (q.v. 'snapshot'). It's a case where all screenshots are the results of screen capture (as you sort of note) but not all screen captures result in screenshots (i.e. for a video a screenshot would be a still frame of it but not the whole video, which is to say the whole screen capture).

Answer (score 5):

Screenshot has more general usage.

The people you'll find use screen capture are people contextually obtaining views from a screen. For instance as a Software Engineer, I often screen capture bugs found with Sprinter.

Screen capture can also refer to a video recording whereas a screenshot only refers to a still image.